# Log into website in Python script

Tags: python, authentication, web, python-requests

I'm trying to log into a website and then perform some tasks to retrieve some data I need. I've been looking at examples of ways to login but nothing I've tried seems to work for my case. I've heard that the "requests" module is something that I should utilize.

Here is the form section of the login page (https://verification.nws.noaa.gov/services/public/login.aspx):

```
<form name="PageForm" method="POST" action="/services/public/login.aspx" id="PageForm">
.
.
(a little ways down)
.
.
     <p>
       <label for="Username">Username:</label>
       <br>
       <input name="UsernameBox" type="text" id="UsernameBox">
     </p>
     <p>
       <label for="Password">Password:</label>
       <br>
     </p>
     <p>
       <input type="submit" name="LoginBtn" value="Login" onclick="javascript: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("LoginBtn", "", true, "", "", false, false))" language="javascript" id="LoginBtn" class="btn">
     </p>
     .
     .
</form>
```

This is what I have for my Python code so far and it doesn't seem to login or work:

```
import requests

# Log into the NWS Performance Management site to get Storm Data.
url = 'https://verification.nws.noaa.gov/services/public/login.aspx?'
values = {'UsernameBox': 'myuser',
          'PasswordBox': 'mypass',
          'LoginBtn': 'Login'}

session = requests.session()
r = session.post(url, data=values)

# Try opening private webpage when logged in.
r = session.get('https://verification.nws.noaa.gov/stormdat/downloads/csv/index.aspx#top')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just missed a few fields in your payload, you can get them from the login [page](https://verification.nws.noaa.gov/services/public/login.aspx).

```
<body><form name="PageForm" method="POST" action="/services/public/login.aspx" id="PageForm">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUIMzc4Mzk0MzlkZF/afEu7JIuhzEtWu2QqdxDm88Un" />
```

So, your values should like like this

```
values = { 
    '__EVENTTARGET': '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__VIEWSTATE'   'Get this value from the login page',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'  'Get this value from the login page',
    'UsernameBox'   'myuser',
    'PasswordBox'   'mypass',
    'LoginBtn'  'Login'
}
```